# What's the relation between product-am and carbon-apimgt?

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I got product-am and carbon-apimgt from github . I want customize the wso2 open source code   like change its ui to chinese, Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

`carbon-apimgt` repository maintains the code of most of the components and features used in WSO2 API Manager. Meanwhile `product-apim` repository is used to build the product and run integration tests on top of the built pack.

However, from wso2am-4.0.0 onwards, UI related code is maintained in [apim-apps repository](https://github.com/wso2/apim-apps). There are 3 separate folders in [this](https://github.com/wso2/apim-apps/tree/main/portals) for each portal (publisher portal, developer portal and admin portal) in API Manager. Choose one portal at a time and start editing the code. You can follow the [read me](https://github.com/wso2/apim-apps#readme) for getting start the work.